# DXImageTransform and parameters question

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I'm using

```
_background-image:none;
_filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img_url', sizingMethod='crop');
```

to make png`s files transparent in IE6. It's working fine, but I can't figure out how to pass parameters like left center no-repeat;

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as such. The [`sizingMethod` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might (but probably won't) help.

Otherwise, you'll have to switch to using a JavaScript-based `.png` fix that supports emulation of those `background-*` properties, such as:

http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/#background_properties